# How to remove the milliseconds in the answer of two different datapickers?

Tags: c#, windows, datapicker

Here is my code, the ouput of this is hours/minutes/sec/milliseconds, and I want to remove the milliseconds. Thanks in advance

```
  System.DateTime date1 = dtpActualStart.Value;
        System.DateTime date2 = dtpEndTime.Value;

        System.TimeSpan diff1 = date2.Subtract(date1);

        metroLabel8.Text = diff1.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
metroLabel8.Text = diff1.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

If you want other formats you can take a look at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. :)